# EntitiyFramework Foreign key return null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I made Ef settings as below.

```
public class Room {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoomIdentificationId")]
    public RoomIdentification Identification { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = true), Required]
    public int RoomIdentificationId { get; set; }
}

public class RoomIdentification {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Floor { get; set; }
    public int RowOnTheFloor { get; set; }
}

public class MTempDbContext : DbContext {

    public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RoomIdentification> RoomIdentifications { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to access the `RoomIdentification` class from the `Room` class It gives `null` error.

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the related entity :

```
var rooms = context.Rooms.Include(x => x.Identification).ToList();
```

For more information see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access it without using include.

Use this:

```
var rooms = context.Rooms.Include(x=> x.Identification).ToList();
```